# dropzone.js breaks on uploading files larger than 10MB

Tags: dropzone.js

Dropzone.js works perfectly fine on uploading files below 10 MB. When I try to upload files larger than 10 MB Dropzone starts uploading and breaks between 80-90%...the exact time is always different. The default `maxSize` is 256MB and I didn't change anything.

Anyone can help with an idea how to debug this?

Thank you so much!

Comment: maybe a setting on your webserver?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/change-the-maximum-upload-file-size

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I thought of this as well, but when I use a normal input field it works perfectly....so that should implement that the server side is properly configured, does it?

Comment: Without dropzone.js it's working!
`<form id="videos" action="/video" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" name="file"></input>
                <button></button>
            </form> `

Comment: maybe try upload in chunks? https://gitlab.com/meno/dropzone/wikis/faq#chunked-uploads